# Существуют ли api для проверки музыки на авторские права?

Tags: php, javascript, java, c++, python

Существуют ли api для проверки музыки на авторские права? я искал, либо плохо искал, так же ковырял ютуб апи но ничего толкового не наковырял, подкиньте пищи для размышления :)

Comment: Что должна делать "проверка на авторские права"?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music - что то на подобии этого, мне нужно проверку сделать на наличие авторских прав. Но сервисов которые предоставляют апи я не нашел, а лисапедить с гет контентами и курлами мне нехочется